# I have a travel insurance policy that comes with card A, and paid for the travel with card B. Is the said travel covered?

Tags: payment-cards, travel-insurance-claim

I have multiple payment cards.

Card A has travel insurance coverage.

Card B does not have such coverage but has the convenience of holding multiple currencies in different accounts and switch to the right one automatically depending on where you pay (Revolut or similar). It has the advantage of minimizing the losses that happen during currency exchange.

In a recent situation, I paid for train tickets using card B. Then, I experienced a disruption during the said travel. Can I claim the incident on the travel insurance of card A?

Comment: Read the fine print but I think it is unlikely.

Answer (score 29):

It depends on the terms of the travel insurance that comes with card A.  To find out, you can either read the terms or just submit the claim and see whether they pay it.

(In my experience, insurance that comes with a credit card applies only when payment is made with that card.  This makes sense, because the point of such benefits is to encourage people to use the card so the card issuer realizes more revenue.  My guess is, therefore, that the insurance will not cover your disruption, but to be sure you'll have to read the terms or submit the claim.)

Comment: That’s indeed the most frequent case, but there are exceptions. There is something in the HSBC UK Premier product (I think it’s the credit card, but it may have been directly with the current account) which covers you whether you paid with the card or not (or at least it did a few years ago). I think it was only for medical issues rather than travel disruption though.

Comment: It really depends on the card in question and one should read the terms. For example, in the case of the card I have, it doesn't matter whether the travel was paid for the card, with the exception of car insure: in that specific rate, the full rental must be paid for with only that card.

Comment: Seconding what @helm says: the only answer is to read the terms. I have two MasterCards from the same bank, for the same bank account. One is a MasterCard Premium, the other a MasterCard Gold. Both come with travel insurance. On the Premium card, the insurance only covers if at least 50% of the trip is bought with that card; on the Gold card, the insurance covers regardless of which card is used.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: What would happen if the traveler booked the service with the card, and attempted to pay with the card when the service was delivered, but for reasons outside the traveler's control the payment couldn't be processed with the card and the service had to be paid for via other means?

Comment: @supercat Then the insurance would cover any events on the journey (on the Premium card, that is). I’m not sure how such a situation could arise, though. The 50% refers to any plane/train/boat tickets, hotels, etc., purchased and paid for at the time of the incident triggering the insurance claim. Say you book a hotel with the card, an incident occurs while you’re at the hotel, you make a claim immediately, and you eventually pay for the hotel a week later when you check out – in this situation, the cost of the hotel would not be counted, because it wasn’t paid when the incident occurred.

Comment: Important correction to the comment above: the first sentence is missing a rather crucial word and should read, “Then the insurance would **not** cover any events…”.